# Are Joomla 1.5.25 templates and extensions fully compatible backwards to Joomla 1.5.15

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, templates, joomla, joomla1.5

I have been tasked with upgrading the template of a Joomla 1.5 website to responsive using Bootstrap (a really tricky thing for me since I have only worked from Joomla 2.5 up to 3.4), so I created a base template on a Joomla 1.5.26 Stable local installation.

Client didn't wanted to share code, so I will have to give only the template file, that is the base template modified, but today they told me Joomla version they are using is 1.5.15 and they won't update it anymore since it was the last version that allowed myisam on mysql config. Template is not finished but they want to test it, so I can't find enough documentation since its very old to confirm template will work properly.

Also I am recoding old extensions to try to use Google Maps API, but I can't find almost any extensions left and I'm trying some but can't know if they can run on previous builds. I didn't even was programming or designing anything by the time these versions were released :( could someone enlighten me?

EDIT: So far version 1.5.15 requires myisam database config to run, so it needs a mySQL version lower than 5.5. With XAMPP 1.7.2 it seems to run fine, just delete all cookies from browser to be able to use phpmyadmin and other things.
Clientside seems to work fine for now, but maybe Google Maps API will require a bit of patience.

Bootstrap running on these antique its a real challenge but it will be done, one way or another. Thinking of publishing a template just in case anyone wants to revive these old systems.

Comment: Whoa, that wall of text is quite scary. Try adding some linebreaks and emphasis to improve readability. (PS: didn't read the whole thing (yet))

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Sorry, I'm kind of desperate, I will style it better

Comment: I've never heard of this MyISAM thing and I think I would know.  I've had lots of 1.5 sites including one that was up until quite recently and that never has come up . They are running extremely dangerously insecure software and if they are having problems it is likely because they have been hacked and don't realize it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html why is it that you need mysql lower than 5.5?  I'm really not understanding the reasoning here.  There is some other reason they don't want to go above 1.5.15.  They may have been scared by this issue https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5259-joomla-1516-released.html  which was a nightmare but you can just go straight to the most recent 1.5 (I'd try it on a sand box). ALso there is an independent repo in github run by Phil Taylor that 1.5.99 that has even newer security updates.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, quite the client you're having to deal with.

I believe the extensions you developer for the latest version of the Joomla 1.5 series will still work on 1.5.15, however, to be sure, I'd suggest installing Joomla 1.5.15 which you can download from here:

http://mirror.myjoomla.io/Joomla_1.5.15-Stable-Full_Package.zip

This ensure there will be no B/C issues

Comment: I'm trying to install it, but mySQL must be god knows which version, XAMPP on 1.7.3 won't even load the phpmyadmin. I'm a front-end designer so this right now its my hardest task so far. (this thing its really really OLD)